# How do I figure out why I cant connect using "wget" to an external web site?

Tags: centos, networking, wget, traceroute

I'm using CentOS 7.  I'm trying to figure out why I can't connect via wget to an external web site, although most other web sites work and I can connect to this other web site from other computers.  The web site is "gitlab.com" and when I try and connect I get timeout errors

```
[root@server tmp]# wget "https://gitlab.com"
--2018-02-24 14:38:00--  https://gitlab.com/
Resolving gitlab.com (gitlab.com)... 52.167.219.168
Connecting to gitlab.com (gitlab.com)|52.167.219.168|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2018-02-24 14:39:04--  (try: 2)  https://gitlab.com/
Connecting to gitlab.com (gitlab.com)|52.167.219.168|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

This is odd because I can connect to most other sites using wget, for instance www.microsoft.com ...

```
[root@server tmp]# wget "https://www.microsoft.com"
--2018-02-24 14:36:55--  https://www.microsoft.com/
Resolving www.microsoft.com (www.microsoft.com)... 23.79.214.159, 2600:1407:10:287::356e, 2600:1407:10:29c::356e, ...
Connecting to www.microsoft.com (www.microsoft.com)|23.79.214.159|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/ [following]
--2018-02-24 14:36:55--  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/
Reusing existing connection to www.microsoft.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: 'index.html.2'

    [ <=>                                                                                                   ] 221,740     --.-K/s   in 0.03s

2018-02-24 14:36:56 (6.74 MB/s) - 'index.html.2' saved [221740]
```

I ran a trace route against the gitlab server, but I'm confused about what the output means

```
[root@server tmp]# traceroute 52.167.219.168
traceroute to 52.167.219.168 (52.167.219.168), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  ssdsemi17.a2hosting.com (70.32.26.14)  0.087 ms  0.014 ms  0.014 ms
 2  75.98.175.211.static.a2webhosting.com (75.98.175.211)  0.468 ms  0.505 ms  0.547 ms
 3  75.98.175.254.static.a2webhosting.com (75.98.175.254)  0.305 ms  0.458 ms  0.435 ms
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

What else should I troubleshoot/check regarding how to connect to this external site?

Comment: The traceroute command traces the path over all of the routers or 'hops' between you and the destination. It doesn't look like it's failing or else it would just hang on one of the hops and I get the same result with a traceroute to that site.. Unfortunately, I am not able to reproduce the error with `wget`. Have you tried connecting to gitlab with a different device?

Comment: Start with `tcptraceroute gitlab.com 443` this will more mimick the traffic done by `wget`